# Count how many instances are created per request of DbContext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, dbcontext

I'm using dependency injection (Ninject) and set

```
kernel.Bind<IApplicationDbContext>().To<ApplicationDbContext>().InRequestScope();
```

to have just one instance of DbConxtect issued by the Ioc container.
This seems to be ok but I want to be sure that during the request there is just the number DbContext instances that I want.

How can I check how many instances of the DbObject are create in my request? I've totally no idea where to check during debugging, please give me some clues to enlighten me.

Comment: What's your goal? Are you trying to test that Ninject is doing what it's supposed to do? If so, I'd leave that to the Ninject developers...

Comment: @topher If there is -for some reason- no active scope (e.g. because you're running in a background thread), Ninject will happily return you new (transient) instances for you without warning. This can lead to hard to track bugs. I therefore find the question not that weird, although I'd probably enforce scoped behavior differently.